# .Net Api for Creating Word Documents with Charts

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Do you know any good library to create Word Documents(Not Excel Sheets) including Charts. 
I tried so far:

1. DocX -> is working, but has not enough options to modify the graph
2. NPOI -> cant get it to work. Throws Error when opening docx with charts in.
3. NetOffice -> couldn´t create a graph.

Also a good Link to a nice documented Example would be appreciated.

I would like to have a good library, which is not as complex as the OOXML Api.
Also it should be free. Office is installed on the running machine.

Thanks Chris

Comment: Try asking in [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), just make sure to read their tour and help center to format your question properly. PS: In DocX you have acess to the xml, and you can edit it directly to add the funcionalities you're missing. A good way to do is create an empty .docx in msword, add the chart you want and check it's xml for the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn´t found any better library so far. So i will continue to use DocX. As Magnetron stated you can modify the XML behind. So you could just do what you want to your chart, read out the XML and modify it your way. 
For example i post a method to change the Axis title on a Word Chart with DocX. The XML region is the needed word xml. With the code you could create this xml.

```
public void SetYTitle(string v)
    {
        #region xml
        //  <c:valAx>
        //      <c:axId val="82091008"/>
        //      <c:scaling>
        //          <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
        //          <c:max val="90"/>
        //          <c:min val="65"/>
        //      </c:scaling>
        //      <c:delete val="0"/>
        //      <c:axPos val="l"/>
        //      <c:majorGridlines/>
        //      <c:title>
        //          <c:tx>
        //              <c:rich>
        //                  <a:bodyPr rot="-5400000" vert="horz"/>
        //                  <a:lstStyle/>
        //                  <a:p>
        //                      <a:pPr>
        //                          <a:defRPr/>
        //                      </a:pPr>
        //                      <a:r>
        //                          <a:rPr lang="de-DE"/>
        //                          <a:t>title y</a:t>
        //                      </a:r>
        //                  </a:p>
        //              </c:rich>
        //          </c:tx>
        //          <c:layout/>
        //          <c:overlay val="0"/>
        //      </c:title>
        #endregion
        XNamespace nsC = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart";
        XNamespace nsA = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main";
        var existent = ResChart.Xml.Descendants().Where(s => s.Name.LocalName.Equals("valAx")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existent != null)
        {
            var title = new XElement(nsC + "title");
            var tx = new XElement(nsC + "tx");
            var rich = new XElement(nsC + "rich");
            var bodyPr = new XElement(nsA + "bodyPr");
            bodyPr.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("rot"), "-5400000");
            bodyPr.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("vert"), "horz");
            var lstStyle = new XElement(nsA + "lstStyle");
            var p = new XElement(nsA + "p");
            var pPr = new XElement(nsA + "pPr");
            var defRPr = new XElement(nsA + "defRPr");
            var r = new XElement(nsA + "r");
            var rPr = new XElement(nsA + "rPr");
            rPr.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("lang"), "de-DE");
            var t = new XElement(nsA + "t");
            t.SetValue(v);
            var layout = new XElement(nsC + "layout");
            var overlay = new XElement(nsC + "overlay");
            overlay.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("val"), "0");

            //build tree
            title.Add(tx);
            tx.Add(rich);
            rich.Add(bodyPr);
            rich.Add(lstStyle);
            rich.Add(p);
            p.Add(pPr);
            pPr.Add(defRPr);
            p.Add(r);
            r.Add(rPr);
            r.Add(t);
            title.Add(layout);
            title.Add(overlay);

            existent.Add(title);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Warn("no axis def existent.");
        }
    }
```

So i´m basically using OOXML to do what I want. Anyway I think its too much overhead for setting a axis title.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at OpenXML?

Here is a link with a sample to create a chart in word https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-create-Chart-into-a7d424f6

Comment: As I stated, I dont want to use OpenXML. I thinks it´s way to much overhead.